# sentence construction: Nothing could be further from the truth

Tags: sentence-construction

> Nothing could be further from the truth.

What's the structure of this sentence? Is it an idiom?

Is it short for

> Nothing could be further (than it) from the truth.

"It" is what you said, or someone's opinion, and the like.

Comment: What about this sentence are you having trouble with? Do you understand "could" here? Do you understand comparative "further" structures? We can answer questions about one specific aspect of English, but we don't break down entire sentences into their structure. Please edit and ask for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nothing could be further from the truth.

This is an idiom and [defined as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nothing%20could%20be%20further%20from%20the%20truth)

> used to say that something is absolutely not true

> I know you think I don't care, but nothing could be further from the truth.

To follow the structure of your original example, we could say

> Nothing could be further than it **is** from the truth.